# Google Places API with google map Api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-place-report

I've used Google Maps as well as Google Places, but I'm not logging in to the program, my plan does not work and errors or Google Places with the error. The following is encountered.

my google Places API error:

> Status{statusCode=PLACES_API_ACCESS_NOT_CONFIGURED, resolution=null}

my google maps error:

> E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for
>   how to correctly set up the map. E/Google Maps Android API: In the
>   Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
>   Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Ensure that
>   the following Android Key exists:

My question is, in fact, how to use both Google Maps and Google Places in one app?

try {

```
                Intent intent =
                        new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                                .build(SourceAddressActivity.this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
            }
```

Comment: This is an incomplete question, and, even if answered, will not help out anyone else struggling with Maps for Android.  You should at least show the relevant portion of the stack trace along with any Java code which you consider relevant.

Comment: you should enable places and map api  in google developer console. And also make sure that yuare adding correct sha1 in the console

Comment: did you enable place and map api from google console https://console.cloud.google.com/